# how to send email to external emails

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have code that checks an outgoing folder for files and if a new one is created it will send a notification email to the designated email. The problem I am having is that it sends the email internally but anyone outside of our server doesn't receive the email. Here is an example of how I have my SMTP setup:

```
$global:smtpTo = ""
$smtpServer    = "mail.mllc.org"
$smtpFrom      = "teresab@medical.org"

$smtp = New-Object -TypeName "Net.Mail.SmtpClient" -ArgumentList $smtpServer

if ("$($deptClient)" -eq "\\vavm\FTP\CINICO\Outgoing\Ruth") {
  Write-Host "$($deptClient)"
  $global:smtpSubject = "$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)"
  $global:smtpTo      = "r@cinico.ky, teresab@medical.org "
}
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom, $global:smtpTo, $global:smtpSubject, $smtpBody)
```

here is the errror I am receiving : `Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay"`

Comment: We don't know enough about your infrastructure to answer the question. Not to mention that the code snippet you posted doesn't even send the mail.

Comment: how much of my infrastructure do you actually need, you only need my smtp details, I have added the send line, It sends the email internally fine and shows both email addresses on the email but the external people are saying that they are not receiving the email, for example teresab@medical.org recieves the email but not r@cinico.ky

Comment: If `mail.mllc.org` is your mail relay, `Send()` doesn't throw an error, and mail gets delivered only to internal recipients, the problem is either on your mail relay or further upstream. Check the mail relay's log and configuration. Nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet introduced in PowerShell v2.0?  That might be easier to use than Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

In any case....

If you're able to receive mail sent to internal addresses and only external addresses fail, that tells me that the problem is probably not with your SMTP client.  That tells me that there's a problem with the SMTP server.  The client doesn't know the difference between internal and external recipients.

You should be checking your SMTP server logs, and ensuring that your SMTP server is allowed to send email to external recipients (i.e., port 25 isn't blocked at your firewall, you have external DNS configured correctly, etc.).